# Using .Net how do I deserialize the following xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have the following xml (see below) that I want to de-serialize to the class Rule. I have not found the magical combination of xml attributes that allows me to store as text the xml content from the Parameters node in my xml input. 
I need an object of type Rule having the property `Name = "Rule1"` and property `Parameters = 
"<User>Tommy</User><Database>local</Database>"`

Thanks in advance.

```
<Rule>
  <Name>Rule1</Name>
  <Parameters>
    <User>Tommy</User>
    <Database>local</Database>
  </Parameters>
</Rule>

class Rule
{
  [XmlElement("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("Parameters")]
  [XmlText(typeof(string))]
  public string Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: I don't think I have been clear enough. I need to have the entire node named Parameters serialized to a string not to a custom class. As an example if an xml document was processed containing this

```
  <Parameters>
    <X>xxxx</X>
    <Y>yyyy</Y>
  </Parameters>
```

I need it deserialized to the string "<X>xxxx<Y>yyyy"
If a different xml document contained this

```
  <Parameters>
    <A>aaaa</A>
    <B>bbbb</B>
  </Parameters>
```

I need it deserialized to the string "<A>aaaa<B>bbbb"

Comment: `Serializable` is not actually necessary for `XmlSerializer`, only for `IFormatter`-based serializers (i.e. `BinaryFormatter`).

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - thanks for the response but your link does not answer my question. I need to deserialize xml formatted text to a string.

Comment: You could just do a google search stop looking for quick fixes without doing the research yourself for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough?

```
XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(xml); //or XElement.Load(...)
Rule rule = new Rule()
{
    Name = (string)xDoc.Element("Name"),
    Parameters = String.Join("",xDoc.Element("Parameters").Elements())
};
```

--

```
class Rule
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Simple enough to be an answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Please consider using the OOP way like `luksan` suggested.**

Otherwise, I would make up two placeholder classes for `XmlSerializer` support and then transform the objects into string maybe like

```
class Rule
{     
  public string Name { get; set; }    
  public string Parameters { get; set; }
}

class XmlRule
{
  [XmlElement("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("Parameters")]
  public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
}

class XmlParameters
{
   [XmlElement("User")]
   public string User { get; set; }
   [XmlElement("Database")]
   public string Database { get; set; }
}

public Rule CreateRule(string xml)
{
    XmlRule xmlRule = Deserialize(xml); // deserialize as you would do usually

    Rule result = new Rule
    {
        Name = xmlRule.Name,
        Parameters = CreateParametersXml(xmlRule.Parameters)
    };

    return result;
}

private string CreateParametersXml(XmlParameters parameters)
{
    return string.Format("<User>{0}</User><Database>{1}</Database>",
                         parameters.User,
                         parameters.Database);
}
```

Maybe not the best solution since the `"<User>{0}</User><Database>{1}</Database>"` stuff is hardcoded, what isn't that nice. But since I think the whole idea of having a non OOP model will cause trouble this seems the most simple solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
public static string DeserializeToString(object obj)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false) };
            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        }
```

It will take an object and convert it to a string, omitting namespaces and XML declarations.

use like:

```
var rule = new Rule();
rule.Name = "name";
rule.Parameters = new Parameters();
rule.Parameters.User = "username";
rule.Parameters.Database = "database";

var stringResults = DeserializeToString(rule);
```